# /var/run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf nameserver contents

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, dnsmasq

Xubuntu 15.10 using Ethernet

From my understanding, `/var/run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf` should contain the nameservers used by dnsmasq to resolve addresses and is configured by a script called by network-manager. In my case, the file contains only `nameserver 127.0.1.1` which doesn't seem right. My IPv4 address of the only network interface on my machine is static and the IPv6 auto-configured. In both cases my router is set as my DNS server. There are the contents `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver fe80::1%eth0
```

dig command shows `;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)` indicating it used dnsmasq for resolution but then what does dnsmasq use?

Note that name resolution is working just fine my questions are whether this setup would break with a reboot and whether IPv6 name resolution works at all. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If your configuration is working at this moment, then even after your system restarts.

`dnsmasq` is configured by a configuration file with the name

```
/etc/dnsmasq.conf
```

and also `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/resolv.conf` are essential and all files in `/etc/dnsmasq.d/` will be considered.

The IP address `127.0.1.1` is ok and, also as `127.0.0.1`, your host or in other words, the `localhost`.

Without a modification in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`, `dnsmasq` reads your `/etc/resolv.conf` and use your router (`192.168.1.1` in your case) as nameserver.

Test it. Search the line

```
#no-resolv
```

in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` and remove the `#`. Now restart `dnsmasq`

```
sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq
```

and try to ping `google.com`. It should fail, if there is no other nameserver defined in your `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`

Comment: I did what you said and restarted dnsmasq.  Showing its log with `service dnsmasq status` it rightfully complains about ignoring resolv-file due to the flag and about no upstream servers configured.  dig and nslookup return a REFUSED status but the system still resolves names. I pinged a website that I haven't visited before and it worked. Something funky is going on here.

Comment: Yes, perhaps. And?

Comment: I just don't like uncertainty.

Comment: Read your question and read my answer. If you have further questions, ask new questions as new questions, but don't in the comments.